# Is variance taken into account when algorithm analysis is performed?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

Silly question. I was wondering if the measure of "variance" is taken into account when the analysis of an algorithm is performed (asymptotic). In general best-case,worst-case,average-case are taken into account, even for more complicated analysis. However is the variance actually used sometimes?

I can imagine that in theory you can perform the analysis, but at my knowledge no-one seems actually to use such measure, and I wonder why.